# Apache httpd.conf using defined variable in if statement

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I try to make a universal httpd.conf using an if statement to decide which port is used.

```
# In HOME the path of the home directory of the apache user is set
PassEnv HOME

Define HTTPServerPath "${HOME}/HTTPServer"

<If "%{HTTPServerPath} -strcmatch '*something*'">
    Define ListenPort 1080
</If>
<Else>
    Define ListenPort 1180  
</Else>
```

This does not work, as the variable from the Define line seems not available. How can I implement such an universal config file?

Comment: Somewhere I found
`<If "'${HTTPServerPath}' -strcmatch '*something*'">`
But also this is not working. Result is always false.

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution for that. The workaround is now to start the service with a different parameter.

Start of service:

```
httpd start -Dsomething
#httpd start -DsomethingElse.
```

httpd.conf

```
<IfDefine something>
...
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine somethingElse>
...
</IfDefine>
```